# how to rotate text around specific point by imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I need render text on circle path but no primitive liketexpath in SVG in imagemagick or graphicmagick document. distort is a little bit strange.

I want to put character on circle edge and rotate text with the angle from the point to center of circle. Is there command like: rotate angle x0,y0?

Comment: I would suggest you find or make an example and add it to your thread. It is always easier to understand a question with an example. You may be looking for a "distort" method like "ScaleRotateTranslate" rather than a rotate.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking and although you did not reply to my comment to confirm what you wanted this may be what you want:

```
convert input.jpg -virtual-pixel background +distort SRT "10,10 30" output.jpg
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt